# scala lifting function having with a collection as argument

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7, lifting

I have a class which accepts a function `f: Option[Seq[Option[A]]] => Option[A]]`

```
case class Function[A](operator: Option[Seq[Option[A]]] => Option[A], name: String, arity: Int)
```

What i would like is for the user of this class to be able to not have to worry about the `Option` framework. So the user would pass a function `g: Seq[A] => A` and under the hood i would lift that function. The lifting part is what i'm not being able to do.

This is what i have (using `optionInstance.lift` of scalaz) :

```
object Function {
  def apply[A](operator: Seq[A] => A) = new Function(optionInstance.lift(operator),"a", 1)
}
```

However this does not compile since the lift operator is returning `Option[Seq[A]]` instead of `Option[Seq[Option[A]]]`. How can this be done?

Comment: We don't how you want to do the mapping. Let's say you have the operator  Seq[A] => A, how would handle the input in the lifted Seq(Some(a), None)) ? I can't think of a canonical way.

Comment: if `Seq(Some(a), None))` would evaluate to `None` as a proper `Option[Seq[_]]` would have to behave right?

Comment: basically the user would provide `Seq[A] => A` and under the hood i would lift it to `Option[Seq[Option[A]]] => Option[A]`.

with `Seq(Some(a), None))` evaluating to `None`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to convert between your two prototypes :

```
  def f[A]: Seq[A] => A = ???

  def g[A]: Option[Seq[Option[A]]] => Option[A] = {
    {
      case None => None
      case Some(seq) if seq.exists(_.isEmpty) => None
      case Some(seq) => Some(f(seq.flatten))
    }
  }
```

You can use this to transform your operator

Comment: say i have `def add(x: Seq[Double]): Double = x.reduce(_+_)`
how do i use your conversor? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to return Option[Seq[Option[A]]] you have to first transform your Seq[A] into a Seq[Option[A]] before doing the lift